# Play AudioStream of WebRTC C++ Application with Audio Device

Tags: c++, webrtc, rtp

I wrote two command line applications in C++ which use WebRTC:

- Client creates a PeerConnection and opens an AudioStream
- Server receives and plays the AudioStream

The basic implementation works: They exchange SDP-Offer and -Answer, find their external IPs using ICE, a PeerConnection and a PeerConnectionFactory with the corresponding constraints are created, etc. I added a hook on the server side to `RtpReceiverImpl::IncomingRtpPacket` which writes the received payload to a file. The file contains valid PCM audio. Therefore, I assume the client streams data successfully through the network to the server application.

On the server side, my callback `PeerConnectionObserver::OnAddStream` is called and receives a `MediaStreamInterface`. Furthermore, i can iterate with my `DeviceManagerInterface::GetAudioOutputDevices` through my audio devices. So basically, everything is fine.

What is missing: I need some kind of glue to tell WebRTC to play my AudioStream on the corresponding device. I have seen that I can get an AudioSink, AudioRenderer and AudioTrack objects. Again: Unfortunatly, I do not see an interface to pass them to the audio device. Can anyone help me with that?

One important note: I want to avoid to debug real hardware. Therefore, I added -DWEBRTC_DUMMY_FILE_DEVICES when building my WebRTC modules. It should write audio to an output file but the file just contains 0x00. The input file is read successfully because as I mentioned earlier, audio is send via RTP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found the solution: First, I have to say that my Code uses a WebRTC from 2017. So, the following things may have been changed and/or are fixed already:

After debugging my code and the WebRTC library I saw: When a remote stream is added, playback should start automatically. There is no need on the developer side to call `playout()` in the `VoiceEngine` or something comparable. When the library recognizes a remote audio stream, playback is paused, the new source is added to the mixer, and playback is resumed. The only APIs to control playback are provided by `webrtc::MediaStreamInterface` which is passed via the `PeerConnectionObserver::OnAddStream`. Examples are `SetVolume()` or `set_enabled()`.

So, what went wrong in my case? I used the `FileAudioDevice` class which should write raw audio data to an output file instead of speakers. My implementation contains two bugs:

- `FileAudioDevice::Playing()` returned true in any case. Due to this, the library added the remote stream, wanted to resume playout, called `FileAudioDevice::Playing()` which returned true and aborted because it thought the AudioDevice was already in playout mode.
- There seems to be a bug in the FileWrapper class. The final output is written in `FileAudioDevice::PlayThreadProcess()` via `_outputFile.Write(_playoutBuffer, kPlayoutBufferSize)` onto disk. However, this does not work. Luckily, a plain C fwrite() as hacky bugfix does work.

Comment: Do you know where exactly to disable automatic audio playback in webrtc source? For my task webrtc must not not play any remote audio at all unless if I explicitly tell in the code to play it